# Call method on subclass given pointer to superclass

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I have a set of buttons in a group:

```
buttons = new QButtonGroup();

button_0 = new MyButton("A", this);
button_1 = new MyButton("B", this);
button_2 = new MyButton("C", this);
```

MyButton is a QPushButton, which inherits QAbstractButton. One MyButton in the group can be selected at a time.

```
MyButton::MyButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton(text, parent)
{
    this->setCheckable(true);
    this->setChecked(false);
}
```

MyButton has an increment method.

```
void MyButton::increment()
{
    this->j++;
}
```

I want to call the increment method on whichever MyButton instance is currently selected. There's a handy `checkedButton()` method that I can call on `buttons`, but that returns a pointer to a QAbstractButton.

I can't call `increment` on the pointer or the QAbstractButton. `buttons->checkedButton()->increment();` yields `error: no member named 'increment' in 'QAbstractButton'`. How can I increment the selected MyButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to let the compiler know that you are using a `MyButton*` rather than a `QAbstractButton*`, and that means a cast.

If you know that the pointer is a `MyButton*` then you can just do a `static_cast<MyButton*>(buttons->checkedButton())->increment();` If you don't know if its a `MyButton*` then you'll need to check, and that'll mean something like this:

```
MyButton* temp = dynamic_cast<MyButton*>(buttons->checkedButton());

if(temp != nullptr) temp->increment();
```

**EDIT:**
[SaZ has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035613/saz) that [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast) is preferable to `dynamic_cast` because:

> It doesn't require RTTI support and it works across dynamic library boundaries

`MyButton` already inherits from `QObject`, but there is one more qualification, that it is declared with `Q_OBJECT`. If both of these qualifications are met then you can simply replace the `dynamic_cast` with a `qobject_cast`:

```
MyButton* temp = qobject_cast<MyButton*>(buttons->checkedButton());

if(temp != nullptr) temp->increment();
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to cast from QAbstractButton to MyButton rather than QAbstractButton* to MyButton*. This should work a lot better!

Comment: Usually, using of `dynamic_cast` is a symptom of bad design. One exception - casting a `sender()` in slots with `qobject_cast`.

Comment: @SaZ `sender()` is a good call *but* only if this method is a `slot` that was called from a message *and* if that message was not called with a lambda. I will edit.

Comment: From my point of view, there should be a parent class with virtual `increment` method. Because writing logic, based on real object types breaks polymorphysm.

Comment: @SaZ Hmmm... I agree with your statement "Because writing logic, based on real object types breaks polymorphism." But I'm not sure that another parent in the hierarchy is the answer, it seems like what should be happening is he passing around of an actual `MyButton*` rather than a `QAbstractButton*` but not having the full pictureof what the code is trying to accomplish I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the case of `QObject` derived classes, you can and should use `qobject_cast()` instead of dynamic cast. It is more efficient by employing the Qt meta system.

Also, unlike the dynamic cast, it will work when compiling without RTTI, and with dynamic libraries as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic cast `QAbstractButton` to `MyButton` and call `increment()`.

```
QAbstractButton* abstractButton = buttons->checkedButton();
MyButton* myButton = dynamic_cast<MyButton*>(abstractButton);
if (myButton)
{
    myButton->increment();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of completeness, in the case of Qt program you may also make use of signal-slot system: if `increment` was declared to be a `slot` then this would work:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(abstractButton, "increment");
```

Comment: And when a signature of `increment` method will be changed - you will forget to change all such string in your code. It is a bad practice.

Comment: + you will get extra warnings in output from Qt.